# Does this need widget Frame or classes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI that would display the text I input in the Entry() unto the Canvas() widget, using the Button widget. Any ideas on why this isn't working?

```
import Tkinter

master = Tkinter.Tk()

Canvass = Tkinter.Canvas(master)
Canvass.pack()

Entry = Tkinter.Entry(master)
Entry.pack()

def CreateText():
    Canvass.create_text(100, 200, anchor="center", text=Entry.get())

Button = Tkinter.Button(text="Press Me",command=CreateText())
Button.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
Button = Tkinter.Button(text="Press Me",command=CreateText())
```

Here, you *execute* the callback method once (adding the current content of the tex field, the empty string, to the canvas), and set the *result* of that function as the callback, i.e. `None`.

Instead, you have to pass the function *itself*, without calling it.

```
Button = Tkinter.Button(text="Press Me",command=CreateText)
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont put braces after method name when giving it to command